# C Changing string passed to function not working

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to pass a string to a function in C to edit that string.
I already know that I should pass a pointer to the string I want to change. However, I get weird results. This is my code, executed with the argument http://www.test.test/test

```
int getAddress(char **newAddress, char *oldAddress);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//retrieving the Address Name from Input
char address[512];
memcpy(address, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1);
printf("%s\n", address);
getAddress((&address), argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", address);
}

int getAddress(char **newAddress, char *oldAddress){
  char *checkAddress;
  checkAddress = strstr (oldAddress, "http://");
   *newAddress = strstr (oldAddress,"www.");
   if(!(newAddress && checkAddress)){
     printf("Please enter a string of the form http://www.example.example\n");
     exit(0);
   }
  *newAddress=strtok(*newAddress, "/");
   printf("%s\n", *newAddress);
  return 1;
  }
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
http://www.test.de/test
www.test.de
Jg��://www.test.de/test
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you ending your strings with backlash 0 (I  typing on a phone, so I can't write the backslash).

Comment: @Cppplus1 The string was copied from `argv[1]`, and the `memcpy` call copies `strlen(argv[1]) + 1` bytes, so it should be NUL-terminated.

Comment: You're assuming incorrectly that pointers and arrays are the same thing.   They are not - the setting of `*newaddress` in the function therefore has undefined behaviour.    You're also not allowing for the possibility of `strtok()` returning a `NULL`.

Comment: 'char **newAddress'. just 'char *newAddress'.  C is maddeningly inconsistent when it comes to passing arrays.  It should require an address operator to get the adderss of the first element, but it does not.  This results in massive confusion and errors.  This: '*newAddress = strstr (oldAddress,"www.");' for example, loads the matching string address into the first [sizeof(char*)] chars of 'char address[512];'.  It's all downhill from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `address` as a `char` *array*.  You then attempt to mutate the `address` *variable* itself by passing it as a `char**`.  That is undefined behavior. (The compiler *should* have warned you about this.) That is, you cannot make an array "point" to something else.  You can modify a *pointer* to point to something else, but [arrays aren't pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)!

It should work if instead you did:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char array[512];
    char* address = array;
    ...
    getAddress(&address, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", address);
}
```

Comment: what is address other than a char array? In other words, what do you mean by passing "adress itself"? What do I have to change to pass it correctly?

Comment: It worked, thank you. Would you mind answering the question of what you meant by the "adress itself"?

Comment: @emilaz I edited my answer to try to be a bit more clear.  Basically you were trying to modify the value of the `address` variable declared in `main`, but in C, arrays cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int getAddress(char **newAddress, char *oldAddress);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
//retrieving the Address Name from Input
    char address[512];
    char *copy = memcpy(address, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1);
    printf("%s\n", copy);
    getAddress(&copy, argv[1]);
    printf("*copy:%s\n", copy);
}

int getAddress(char **newAddress, char *oldAddress)
{
    char *checkAddress;
    checkAddress = strstr (oldAddress, "http://");
    *newAddress = strstr (oldAddress,"www.");

    if(!(newAddress && checkAddress))
    {
        printf("Please enter a string of the form http://www.example.example\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    *newAddress = strtok(*newAddress, "/");
    printf("*newAddress:%s\n", *newAddress);
    return 1;
 }
```

Try this code. Is this what you wanted to achieve? Did you use -Wall flag when compiled the code? It has shown warning: passing argument 1 of ‘getAddress’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  getAddress(&address, argv[1]); which occured because you did getAddress((&address), argv[1]); - this won't work.

```
char *copy = memcpy(address, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])+1);
    printf("%s\n", copy);
    getAddress(&copy, argv[1]);
```

Instead we should have to use a pointer to string and pass it as an argument to getAddress function. I hope this helps you))